# How to Enable Notepad++ ASCII Code Lookup Panel?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in Notepad++ to list ASCII codes?  For instance I'd like to use a panel to quickly reference that ASCII code 97 is character 'a'.

Answer (score 12):

It's called the ASCII Insertion Panel:

Edit => Character Panel